# SQL JOIN STRUGGLE

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SELECT Count(TRK.REACTIE_ID), 
       S.UITGEVER, 
       S.NAAM, 
       S.BESCHRIJVING, 
       S.AFBEELDING_BESTANDSPAD, 
       S.SUBTITLE, 
       C.NAAM 
FROM   CATEGORIEEN_KOPPELTABEL CK 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORIE C 
                    ON C.CATEGORIE_ID = CK.CATEGORIE_ID 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TV_SHOW S 
                    ON S.TV_SHOW_ID = CK.TV_SHOW_ID 
                       AND S.NAAM = 'South Park' 
       FULL OUTER JOIN TVSHOW_REACTIES_KOPPELTABEL TRK 
                    ON TRK.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID 
GROUP  BY TRK.TV_SHOW_ID, 
          S.UITGEVER, 
          S.NAAM, 
          S.BESCHRIJVING, 
          S.AFBEELDING_BESTANDSPAD, 
          S.SUBTITLE, 
          C.NAAM;
```

I can't figure out why I can't get only the first row back.

Now I get three rows back with null values and I want only to get the first row. Please help!

Comment: `WHERE C.CATEGORIE_ID IS NOT NULL`

Comment: You have exactly 3 rows in `CATEGORIEEN_KOPPELTABEL` and **`OUTER`** `JOIN` means, keep them in the result, even if `CATEGORIE`,`TV_SHOW` or `TVSHOW_REACTIES_KOPPELTABEL` dont have matching values.

Comment: it might help if you showed your results and how they are wrong.

Comment: Couldn't paste an image :(, not enough points yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rows without nulls use the following FROM statement and keep the rest of query the same.:

```
FROM   CATEGORIEEN_KOPPELTABEL CK 
     JOIN CATEGORIE C ON C.CATEGORIE_ID = CK.CATEGORIE_ID 
     JOIN TV_SHOW S ON S.TV_SHOW_ID = CK.TV_SHOW_ID AND S.NAAM = 'South Park' 
     JOIN TVSHOW_REACTIES_KOPPELTABEL TRK ON TRK.TV_SHOW_ID = S.TV_SHOW_ID
```